# Store a sentence in a variable (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch file, and whenever their is a user input field, which the user enter a word or a sentence and it get stored in a text file. I made all the job done.

But when the user's input is more than 1 word, it gives the following error:

```
*second word* was unexpected.
```

How can this be solved?

```
@echo off
color f0
:menu
cls
echo Batch Editor
echo Choose what you want to do:
echo 1) New Document
echo 2) Load existing document
echo 3) Learn How to Use
echo 4) Exit
set /p menu=
if %menu%==1 goto new
if %menu%==2 goto load
if %menu%==3 goto learn
if %menu%==4 goto exit
if [%1]==[]  goto learn
echo Invaild Code
pause
goto menu 

:new
cls
echo You have chosen to start a new document.
echo But please note that is impossible to know how to code
echo without seeing the "How to Learn" section.
echo Choose:
echo 1) Continue anyways
echo 2) Go to the "How to Learn" section
echo 3) Exit
set /p type=
if '%type%'=='' goto new
if %type%==1 goto newdoc
if %type%==2 goto learn
if %type%==3 goto exit
echo Invaild Key
pause
goto new

:newdoc
cls
set /p input=
if %input%==Qsave goto saving
if %input%==qsave goto saving
if %input%==qSave goto saving
if %input%==QSAVE goto saving
goto newdoc1
pause

:newdoc1
set /p chosen=
if '%chosen%'==''(
goto newdoc2)
else if "%chosen%"=="Qsave" (
goto saving)
else if "%chosen%"=="qsave" (
goto saving)
else if "%chosen%"=="qSave" (
goto saving)
else if "%chosen%"=="QSAVE" (
goto saving)
else (
goto newdoc2)


:newdoc2
set /p chosen=
if '%chosen%'==''(
goto newdoc1)
else if %chosen%==Qsave (
goto saving)
else if %chosen%==qsave (
goto saving)
else if %chosen%==qSave (
goto saving)
else if %chosen%==QSAVE (
goto saving)
else (
goto newdoc1)
:saving
cls
echo Saving
pause

:load
echo LOADING
pause

:learn
echo Learn
pause

:exit
cls
set /a exiting=0
echo Are you sure you want to exit?
echo Choose:
echo 1)Exit
echo 2)Go Back to the Main Menu
set /p exiting=
if %exiting%==1 exit
if %exiting%==2 goto menu
echo Invaild key
pause
goto exit
pause
exit
```

Comment: The first step would be adding the code of that batch file into the question. Click the `edit` link under the question, paste the relevant part of code, select the pasted text, press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block.

Comment: @wOxxOm the code is not important
anyways just take it as
*at*echo off
set /p type=
echo %type%
pause

Comment: Eh? Got no problem here, screenshot: https://puu.sh/kgVXG/8348943bda.png

Comment: Your example code is working fine. Give an example of a user input that fails for you.

Comment: @Stephan Ok I posted the whole code

Comment: ah - I see: your Problem isn't with a variable, but with `if` Syntax. Why do you use different approaches? (`if "%var%"`, `if '%var%'`, `if %var%` ?. Doubleqoutes are the best choice.

Comment: @CyberShadow you should read `IF /?` and also `SET /?`

Answer (score 0):

You really should post what you currently have, if all you're trying to do is store user inputted text to a text file, something like this might help?

```
SET /P Answer=Say somthing witty! 
ECHO %Answer%>Response.txt
```

Comment: No,  I have done this. I want to store a sentence inside the variable. Try the code I wrote in the edit. In the input write 2 or more words and you will get an error. Thanks for trying anyways

Comment: I see nothing in that batch file that even remotely comes close to the question at hand. Granted, yes I see alot of things that I'd personally do different. But nothing related to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
set var=Alpha beta Gamma
if %var%==whatever
```

is translated to:

```
if Alpha beta Gamma==whatever
```

`IF` Syntax is `IF <Argument1> <comparator> <Argument2> <command>`

Argument1 is `Alpha`, Comparator is `beta` - wait, this is wrong...

It leads to "beta was unexpected", because there should be a compatator (`==`), not an Argument.

Better Syntax:

```
if "%var%"=="whatever"
```

is translated to:

```
if "Alpha beta Gamma"=="whatever"
```

Argument1 is `"Alpha beta Gamma"`, Comparator is `==`, Agrument2 is `"whatever"` - fine Syntax.

Comment: This is a good method if I new what the user input would be. But I don't. I can't say if "%var%"=="whatever" because I don't know what "whatever" is

Comment: What? Why asking the user if you know what he will answer??  By the way: you may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Sample menu where there are only three possible choices plus one covering mistype:

```
@echo off
:retry
cls
```

Unset the variable `M`

```
set M=
```

If nothing typed, then set `M` to 4

```
SET /P "M=Type 1 for pizza, 2 for soup or 3 for exit, then press ENTER: " || set "M=4"
```

Here we use variable substring. See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

```
IF [%M:~0,1%]==[1] goto pizza
```

If `M` are not set to 1, then go to the next line, etc...

```
IF [%M:~0,1%]==[2] goto soup
```

If `M` are not set to 1 or 2 then check if it's set to 3, there is the last `IF` statement, we can now use `else` to cover everything else in the variable `M`

```
IF [%M:~0,1%]==[3] (
    echo Bye...
    @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
    exit /b 0
    ) else (
    goto :retry
)

:pizza
echo Pizza
goto :EOF

:soup
echo Soup
goto :EOF
```

**Edit**: My if statement was a bit redundant, see the revision history to see what I mean.

Comment: Okay this is helpful and make things more neat but you didn't answer my problem. I want to store a sentence in a variable.

Comment: @CyberShadow I showed you how to store a sentence in a variable. It's the line that contain `set /p` and also I showed you how to write and use `IF` and `ELSE`

Comment: I know I am asking too much but how can I do this to my code? I tried the one you gave but gave me an error. I am still new to bat maybe I didn't use your code well